# "If not" vs "If it is not"

Tags: word-choice, negation, conditionals

You were sent a package.
If it is not received please call customer support.

or

You were sent a package.
If not received please call customer support.

Which version is correct?  Is there a better version?

Comment: My suggested wording would be: _"If you don't receive it, please call customer support."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.

The second is using a form of elision that is only appropriate in some contexts like notices and headlines, but since this text is presumably in a notice, that's okay.

If this was part of a larger piece of running text, that would not be okay.

If this was followed by a larger piece of text, then it likely would be okay. Indeed it would be ideal; such headline-style notes are good for small pieces of text in a larger font or otherwise made particularly prominent, then followed by more detailed text that gives a fuller description. The elision of some words helps it stand out (one of the reasons the style is also used in headlines).

Answer (score 1):

"If it is not received" is more correct. "If not received" is sort of short-hand. It's not really correct grammar. The only thing I can think of that might be better is "If you do not receive it..."

Comment: Agreed.  A better alternative could be "If you do not receive it in x days, please call customer support."  Advantage being an expected time for delivery.  In a formal communication, I'd avoid the "If not received..." format.